# Generating form with hidden input and submitting to an action

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, forms

I thought this would be a lot simpler than it had been. I need to extract data from a cell in my datatable (Which I can do) and then submit it via a form with a hidden field in order to pass the variable to an action in my controller.

I am doing something similar to this prior in my code with the exception of generating the form.

I have tried different methods and not matter what when I access the collection in my action the value is null.

My View function:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function () {
            var serial = table.cell(this).data();


            var form = $('<form action="@Url.Action("status")" id="hiddenform"><input type="hidden" id="serial" name="serial" value=""></form>').appendTo('body');
            $('.serial').val(serial);
            form.submit();


        });
```

and my controller I am parsing to:

```
//Accept GET and POST
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Status(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
    {
        string serial = collection["serial"];

        if (serial == null || serial == "")
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Serial is NULL");

        return View(serial);
    }
```

To be honest I have butchered my code a lot in an attempt to fix this so it looks pretty awful.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am receiving the Error: Serial is NULL popup every time in my controller. However if I test the JQuery the value is not null it returns the correct value.

Comment: `$('.serial').val(serial);` after this try to trigger the change event as you are cahnging the value using code and not as user input. `$('.serial').trigger('change');`

Comment: @Manish The value is still null after implementing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the method signature to the following?

```
public ActionResult Status(string serial)
```

where serial will be the parameter name that you will pass from the HTML form.

If the parameter name is blah in HTML, you might have to change your method signature to below:

```
public ActionResult Status(string blah)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden field has a name and id property of serial, but the jQuery selector used to assign a value is looking for a class.  Try # instead to select by ID:

```
$('#serial').val(serial);
```

Alternatively you can use jQuery to AJAX POST the data to your controller:

```
$.post( '@Url.Action("status")', { serial: table.cell(this).data() } );
```

And adjust your controller to expect a parameter of serial:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Status(string serial)
{
    if (serial == null || serial == "")
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Serial is NULL");

    return View(serial);
}
```

Comment: Hello Mike, Sorry it still comes through with the NULL value after this change.

Comment: I would try three things at this point:

1) Use the browser developer tools to check network traffic - is the serial parameter being sent in the request on form submit?  Does it have a value at that point?  If yes, then the issue's on the .NET side.  If no:

2) Put a breakpoint or console.log on the line before the .val() call.  Does the variable serial have a value?

3) Check $('#serial').val(); using console.log right after the assertion but before form.submit().  Does it have a value?

Comment: Using your alternative solution sounds nice in theory, but after implementing it I receive a Server 500 error when the JQuery executes.

Comment: also I know the value being submitted is not null as I tested with popups and just now breakpoints. However when I try to access it at the action it is null.