# Parsing data from Datatable cell to Controller with JQuery, receiving null value

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I thought this would be a lot simpler than it had been. I need to extract data from a cell in my datatable (Which I can do) and then submit it via a form with a hidden field in order to pass the variable to an action in my controller.

I am doing something similar to this prior in my code with the exception of generating the form.

I have tried different methods and not matter what when I access the collection in my action the value is null. However if I test during the JQuery with a popup the value is not null.

So I believe the issue is either with the parsing or with the reading in my Controller. However I am doing the same thing elsewhere in another controller so I believe it to be the parsing.

My View function:

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function () {
            var serial = table.cell(this).data();


            var form = $('<form action="@Url.Action("status")" id="hiddenform"><input type="hidden" id="serial" name="serial" value=""></form>').appendTo('body');
            $('#serial').val(serial);
            form.submit();


        });
```

and my controller I am parsing to:

```
//Accept GET and POST
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Status(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection collection)
{
    string serial = collection["serial"];

    if (serial == null || serial == "")
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Error: Serial is NULL");

    return View(serial);
}
```

To be honest I have butchered my code a lot in an attempt to fix this so it looks pretty awful.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am receiving the Error: Serial is NULL popup every time in my controller. However if I test the JQuery the value is not null it returns the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the method signature to the following?

```
public ActionResult Status(string serial)
```

where `serial` will be the parameter name that you will pass from the HTML form.

If the parameter name is `blah` in HTML, you might have to change your method signature to below:

```
public ActionResult Status(string blah)
```

Comment: Thank you! To be honest I tried something akin to this before however something else in my code at the time must have been stopping it from working.

Comment: I have the same question (pretty much) open here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987658/generating-form-with-hidden-input-and-submitting-to-an-action

if you answer there I will give you the answer there as well!